# Ajax no refresca mi SQL para sacar en tiempo real los datos de mi tabla

Tags: ajax

He construido un Chat que funciona a la perfección, pero he usado Ajax para sacar los datos de la base de datos en tiempo real, pero desconozco la razón por la que este no esta funcionando. Cuando abro la consola de desarrollador en **Chrome** puedo observar que este esta enviado peticiones al servidor pero no me esta refrescando los datos porque si inserto algo en la base de datos no me esta apareciendo de forma automática en mi Chat como debería de suceder.

**

### Ajax:

**

```js
function tiempoReal()
    {
        var tabla = $.ajax({
            url:'./messege/emisor.php',
            dataType:'text',
            async:false
        }).responseText;

        document.getElementById("sala").innerHTML = tabla;
    }
setInterval(tiempoReal, 1000);
```

**

### Chat HTML:

**

```html
<div id="sala"></div>
            
            <div id="chat-sala" class="chat-sala">
            
                <?php
                // Incluye el archivo para obtener todos los mensajes
                require 'messege/emisor.php';
                foreach($mensajes as $mensaje) :
                    if($mensaje['id_emisor'] == $receptor) {
                        // Este mensaje fue enviado por el otro usuario
                        $clase = 'black-text emisor left grey lighten-4';
                    } else {
                        // Este mensaje fue enviado por el usuario en sesión
                        $clase = 'white-text right pink receptor';
                    }
                    // Obtener datos del emisor
                    $usuario = $usuarios[$receptor];
                ?>
                    <!-- Mensajes que me han enviado | Receptor -->
                    <div class="col s12 messege-row">

                        <!-- Para que la img no se repitan -->
                        <?php if($mensaje['id_emisor'] == $receptor) : ?>
                            
                            <!-- Si tiene foto de perfil -->
                            <?php if($usuario['photo_profile'] != false) : ?>
                                <img src="img-profile/<?php echo $usuario['photo_profile']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $usuario['name']; ?>" class="col s2 m2 xl1 img-adaptable circle" height="50">
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <img src="images/user.png" alt="<?=$usuario['name']?>" class="col s2 m2 xl1 img-adaptable circle" height="50">
                            <?php endif ?>

                        <?php endif ?>

                        <span class="<?php echo $clase; ?>" title="<?php echo $mensaje['create_at_messege']; ?>">
                            <?php echo $mensaje['messege']; ?>
                            
                            <?php if($mensaje['photo_messege'] == true) : ?>
                                <img src="messege-photo/<?php echo $mensaje['photo_messege']; ?>" alt="Una foto">
                            <?php endif ?>
                            
                        </span>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
```

Tengo que refrescar la pagina yo mismo por mi cuenta para poder ver lo mensajes nuevos. Todo funciona correcto menos la parte de `Ajax`

NOTA: No me esta lanzado ningún error ni por consola y en la pantalla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun el codigo, estas actualizando el div sala, pero no el div chat-sala, algo a considerar.
Lo otro es que cuando haces la llamada en la primera carga, se ve que iteras por cada elemento de la respuesta de emisor, pero no haces lo.mismo en la respuesta del ajax.
Te recomiendo revisar esas dos cosas.

Comment: Es que cuando intento actualizar el div `chat-sala` y recargo la pagina, este carga bien, pero pasado un segundo como esta definido en el `Ajax` entonces la pantalla se pone en blanco.

Comment: Y como convertis la respuesta del llamado de ajax en codigo html? O tu php devuelve html?

Comment: Si, porque antes de agregarle el `Ajax` para que refresque la pagina ya mi *PHP* devolvía los datos de forma correcta, ósea eso significa que los devolvía en HTML porque todo funcionaba de forma correcta

Comment: Se ve que en tu primera carga se crea codigo html con la respuesta. A esto me refiero -->  //Incluye el archivo para obtener todos los mensajes
                require 'messege/emisor.php';
                foreach($mensajes as $mensaje) :
                    if($mensaje['id_emisor'] =

Comment: Sii, eso mismo estoy haciendo

Comment: Deberias hacer algo similar en tu ajax, añadiendo la respuesta parseando el resultado y creando codigo html con javascript. Creo que no podes incrustar directo la respuesta de tu llamada al emisor.php

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120013/discussion-between-braylin-ivan-payano-and-victor-gonzalez-chamorro).

Comment: Pero como lo puedo hacer, no soy experto en JavaScript